# Problems about find conditions in recursive = 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

this is my debug $this->Subjob->find('all')

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'Subjob' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'job_id' => '2',
        'subjob_title' => 'mastersubsjob',
    ),
    'Job' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'content_id' => '2',
        'Content' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'content_type_id' => '2',
            'content_title' => 'masterdata' //
```

I set recursive = 2 and I want to search Subjob by content_title ,
this is my controller

```
 $conditions[] = array('Content.content_title LIKE'=>'%'.$this->data['Subjob']['content_title'].'%');
```

$this->set('subjobs', $this->paginate($conditions));

but I get "Database Error Unknown column 'Content.content_title' in 'where clause'".

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could you show your  complete `->find()` call? (with conditions et. al.)

Comment: it just $conditions[] like above  and set $this->paginate($conditions) ,error occur when i implement conditions 'Content.content_title LIKE' but it's ok when conditions is 'subjob_title LIKE' ,Is it about deep recursive?

Comment: why not using containable then?

Comment: Also, if Job or Content are not belongsTo or hasOne relationships, they will not be joined on the same query and you can't add conditions against them. Most data is pulled as separate queries and then merged later.